# Severe error in re-deploying servlet - silly error

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I was trying to redeploy a servlet I had recently undeployed but kept getting a `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException`. Tomcat wasn't able to load the context properly.

This is what triggered the search:

```
FAIL - Unable to delete [/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/Catalina/localhost/app.xml].
       The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
```

Here are the errors from the log `catalina.out`, rearranged to fit the column:

```
WARNING: Calling stop() on failed component [{0}] to trigger clean-up
         did not complete.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
         An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([after_stop]) for 
         component [org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext@13150fc] in state
         [FAILED]

WARNING: Error while removing context [/app]
java.lang.ClassCastException:
         org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext cannot be cast to 
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
```

Scrolling back up, I noticed a whole list of `SEVERE` errors, beginning with:

```
SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml for /app
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
    systemId: file:/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/app.xml/;
    lineNumber: 1;
    columnNumber: 1;
    Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

This is not related to [Cannot Undeploy a web-app completely in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873219/) or [Installing JSTL results in org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613918/), though I wasted quite some time looking through these. Everything seemed to be as it should be, so I was stumped. Eventually, I solved it myself. My answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had deployed

```
/path/to/servlet/web/
```

as the XML Configuration file instead of

```
/path/to/servlet/website.xml
```

as Tomcat had been expecting.

A quick check in the saved form content of my other browser revealed this kickself error, so I am posting a Q and A here in the hope that this could save someone some time.

Please be careful when deploying manually, people.